# How do I install version 1.3.6 of sphinx on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

For a test of compiling some other package I require the exact version of `sphinx` on my Ubuntu 18.04.01.

I tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get install sphinx=1.3.6
```

but it says that there is no 'package sphinx'.

So how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - there is only one package for Sphinx named as `sphinx` - it is [its source package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=sphinx).

According to the search results on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you can get only *1.6.7-1ubuntu1* version.

But if you need only Python binding - you can try to install it from `pip`/`pip3`.

Other possible solution is to build older *1.3.6-2ubuntu1* Sphinx (from 16.04 LTS) from source.

---

If you want to **take all the risk (as you will never get the security updates for Sphinx)** then continue with manual installation of Sphinx 1.3.6 on Bionic:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sphinx/libjs-sphinxdoc_1.3.6-2ubuntu1_all.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sphinx/python-sphinx_1.3.6-2ubuntu1_all.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sphinx/python3-sphinx_1.3.6-2ubuntu1_all.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sphinx/sphinx-common_1.3.6-2ubuntu1_all.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sphinx/sphinx-doc_1.3.6-2ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo apt install ./*sphinx*.deb
```

and pin (lock) installed Sphinx packages:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-sphinx
Package: libjs-sphinxdoc
Pin: version 1.3.6-2ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: python3-sphinx
Pin: version 1.3.6-2ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: python-sphinx
Pin: version 1.3.6-2ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: sphinx-common
Pin: version 1.3.6-2ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: sphinx-doc
Pin: version 1.3.6-2ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337

EOF
```

**To make your system more secure consider to remove this pin-file after the compilation of dependent packages with `sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-sphinx` and upgrade to supported Sphinx with `sudo apt dist-upgrade`**.